# Can I use a powered mixer as an unpowered mixer via the effects loop output?

Tags: mixer

Using the 1/4" Line Out of an Effects Loop, can I use a powered mixer as an unpowered mixer without damaging the mixer? 
I understand I would never send the speaker outputs from a powered mixer to active monitors, but don't know if this is a safe thing to do.
Any help is greatly appreciated,
Bruce

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's certainly safe: the effects insert has nothing to do with the power amp. Whether it works the way you want depends on the particular console, but normally it should be fine (especially if you don't need the return).

BTW, powered outputs aren't actually so dangerous: the main difference between a line out and a power out is not voltage (though high-power amps also have a lot of that), but *current capability*. When you connect a power out (at reasonably low level) to a DI with sufficient pad ability, you should get a usable signal (the high impedance means no substantial current will actually flow, the power amp is thus working ”without power”). Just don't connect a full-blown power amp straight to e.g. a sensitive mic input...